# Getting Light Gray Canvas and other missing basemaps to show in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, basemap, arcgis-10.7

I don't have Light Gray Canvas, Dark Gray Canvas, and others in my Add Basemap window.
I am using ArcMap 10.7.1
[image]

How can I get those added into my add basemap window?
So that it can be like this -
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Basemaps you have available to you in ArcMap are based on your current location.  For example, if you're in the USA you'll have some different basemaps available compared to if you're in Mexico, India, or the UK.

Here are the available basemaps for those four examples from above:

USA
[image]

Mexico
[image]

India
[image]

UK
[image]

There are likely other basemaps available (or not available) for other countries as well.

To get the additional basemaps in your ArcMap you will need to be using your ArcMap in a country where those basemaps are offered.  You could possibly request for Esri or your local distributor to make them available in your country, or look into making your own (I'm not sure if that's a possibility for you).

Answer (score 0):

The basemap gallery will also depend on whether or not you are signed into AGOL / Portal. If you are a member of an organization with an AGOL account, your "add basemap" menu will show all basemaps that your AGOL / Portal administrator has added.

Note that if you are on Portal, there is an additional step of adding the Portal connection via ArcGIS Administrator, as detailed in the [Esri docs here](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/use-with-desktop.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_534771F9137A49F4BFF5168C58B3C411). For AGOL, you can just click **Sign In** on the **File** menu.

See the [Enterprise documentation](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/customize-basemaps.htm) for more information about configuring available basemaps.